# How to perform view pager on click listner from its fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to figure out how to perform view pager click listener from its fragment. My scenario is like i have description in fragment which is large so providing a read more button. I want to increase the size of view pager since its inside expandable list view. I thought of perform a click listener from fragment button click but could nit find anything on internet. Can some one please provide me any reference or tutorial where i can figure this out.

Comment: For down Voters Please Answer the Question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textview which is expandable, may be this link help out [click here](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView)

Comment: Since I am using view pager inside expandable list view ,I need to set its height from the fragment